# Как продвинуть "название сайта" в поисковике ?

Tags: seo

У меня есть сайт в стиле name2myname.ru (название взято совершенно произвольно, не переходите по нему).

Мне требуется, чтобы в гугл и яндекс при вводе в строке поиска name2myname первым в поисковой выдаче вылезал мой сайт.

Для гугл мое место в поисковом выдаче - 49. Для яндекса - 4.

Comment: @Alexander Dee, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: ответ дан, но не то, что я хотел узнать.

Answer (score 4):

На эту тему много хороших статей, в том числе, их можно найти там, где Вы хотите продвинуть сайт.

В целом суть такая:

1. Организовать максимум посещений сайта с разных IP. Это главное. Всё остальное этому только способствует, а не заменяет.
2. Разместить на сайте интересный, уникальный контент (об этом, имхо, надо было думать раньше).
3. Добавить в шапку метатеги с ключевыми словами.
4. Добавить сайт в каталоги.

Comment: Это все уже сделано, сайт в сети больше года, по некоторым позициям входит в ТОП-10, но название сайта все равно не продвигается. Я почему этот вопрос задаю: вижу по статистике, что мои клиенты ищут отзывы о моей компании через поисковики, задавая в качестве запроса имя домена, например: "name2myname отзывы".

Comment: Я не эксперт в области СЕО и не могу говорить что-то с уверенностью, но тем не менее, предположу, что название вашего сайта (компании) имеет просто слишком много упоминаний на различных бизнес-каталогах, которые имеют СЕО показатели гораздо выше, чем у вас, вот поэтому они и обходят вас в выдаче. Но что-то говорить с уверенностью, обладая только той инфой, что вы предоставили, я думаю никто не сможет. Может ссылочку на зацен подгоните?:)??